# add text on top and bottom page border

Tags: border

How can I add text on the top and bottom border as seen in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome toTeX SX! I would suggest doing that with the `eso-pic` package.

Comment: See `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{...}`.